# Adding new column to CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv

I would like to add a new column to my CSV in Python. I understand that in Python I will have to run the CSV and rewrite a new one as an output to add a column.

I want to run though each UserID and assign a UniqueID to it.

This is my **input**:

```
UserID,name
a,alice
a,alice
b,ben
c,calvin
c,calvin
c,calvin
```

This is my desired **output**:

```
UniqueID,UserID,name
1,a,alice
1,a,alice
2,b,ben
3,c,calvin
3,c,calvin
3,c,calvin
```

I am new to Python and was wondering if anyone can show me how this can be done.
Thanks.

```
Here is my code so far: 
import csv
import operator

temp_index = 0

with open("./coordinates.csv") as all_coordinates_csv:
    coordinate_reader = csv.reader(all_coordinates_csv, delimiter=",")

    sort = sorted(coordinate_reader,key=operator.itemgetter(0))

with open("./sorteduserid.csv","wb") as sorteduser_csv:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(sorteduser_csv,delimiter=",")
    csv_writer.writerows(sort)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We expect you to show some effort. A good  start would be reading [the documentation of the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html).

Comment: Is the only difference between the UserID and the UniqueID that UniqueID is a number? So UserID is already unique, but a string and you want an integer as ID?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured out how to import my CSV using python and has sorted my UserIDs using the sorted function. I know I need to create an index, but can't seem to figure out how to proceed.

The UniqueID runs through the UserIDs and assigns a unique number to it, so all a's are 1, all b's are 2, etc.

Comment: Nice, so from a UserID you now have a unique integer that you want to use as UniqueID? Then, for each row in ``sort``, you can add the unique id to the row with something like ``csv_writer.writerow([unique_id] + row)``. Note the difference between ``writerow()`` and ``writerows()``. Here,  a singel ``row`` from your example would be e.g. ``['a', 'alice']``.

Answer (score 3):

Take a try with my code:

```
import csv
import uuid

is_first = True
with open('test.csv', newline='') as input_file:  
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        for row in reader:
            if is_first:
                row.insert(0, 'UniqueID')
                is_first = False
            else:
                row.insert(0, str(uuid.uuid4()))

            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on your own attempt:

```
import csv
import operator
from itertools import groupby

with open("./coordinates.csv") as all_coordinates_csv:
    coordinate_reader = csv.reader(all_coordinates_csv, delimiter=",")

    sort = sorted(coordinate_reader,key=operator.itemgetter(0))

grouped = []
for key, group in groupby(sort, lambda x: x[0]):
    grouped.append(list(group))

data_out = [];
data_out.append(['Unique_ID', (grouped[0])[0][0], (grouped[0])[0][1]])

user_id = 1
for group in grouped[1:]:
    for user in group:
        data_out.append([user_id,user[0],user[1]])
    user_id += 1

with open("./sorteduserid.csv","wb") as sorteduser_csv:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(sorteduser_csv,delimiter=",")
    csv_writer.writerows(data_out)
```

After you sort your input the program uses `groupby` to group the values by UserID in `sort`. It then uses those grouped values in the loops to assign a unique ID to each UserID. Before the loops, it extends the header with `User_ID` entry.