# Keyword Detection in CSV and add to new column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have real estate properties and their details (17 columns) in a CSV file (nearly half a million entries). One of the columns provides a location but is actually somewhat a bit too detailed. I want to categorize my entries so I want to simplify the location to give me more generic areas. I would have the areas I want to categorize the entries into in a list such as:

```
keywords = ['Downtown','Park View','Industrial District', ... ]
```

So ideally I would like to take an entry that has for example `Sky Tower Downtown Los Angeles` and then classify it as `Downtown`.

So the task is to first detect the keyword in the `location` column and then append it to a new column (right beside it if possible). If no keyword is found in the entry, I would to classify it as `Other`.

It would look something like this:

| Date | Record_Type | Location | Proterty_Type | ... | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19-Mar-21 | Active Listing | Sky Tower Downtown Los Angeles | Apartment | ... | 15000 |
| 19-Mar-21 | Active Listing | Central Park Residential Tower, 5th Avenue | Apartment | ... | 17000 |
| 20-Mar-21 | Active Listing | Meadow Gardens, Park View | Villa | ... | 125000 |

To something like:

| Date | Record_Type | Location | Area | Proterty_Type | ... | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19-Mar-21 | Active Listing | Sky Tower Downtown Los Angeles | Downtown | Apartment | ... | 15000 |
| 19-Mar-21 | Active Listing | Central Park Residential Tower, 5th Avenue | Other | Apartment | ... | 17000 |
| 20-Mar-21 | Active Listing | Meadow Gardens, Park View | Park View | Villa | ... | 125000 |

Finally it saves it all to a new csv file. I would also ideally like yo use `pandas` to read/write on the csv.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I have tried methods such as the following threads, but I get errors and I don't know whats wrong, so Im open to fresh ideas.

[How to append a new column to a CSV file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882130/how-to-append-a-new-column-to-a-csv-file-using-python)

[Adding new column to CSV in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47825184/adding-new-column-to-csv-in-python)

Comment: How would you classify for example `Meadow Gardens, Park View, Downtown`? Park View or Downtown?

Comment: This is far too broad. What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, pandas has the `read_csv()` and `Series.str.contains()` methods which seem a good place to start

Comment: Ideally, most cases do not have multiple keywords in their string, but if I do< would take the last keyword. If that is tricky, either the first keyword detected or classify it as `Other` and I can manually check it later.

Comment: @G.Anderson I am using `df = pd.read_csv(r'listings.csv', names=col_names, skiprows=[0])` to import the data and `col_names` is from a list I defined before importing.

Comment: That would be good detail to [edit] into your question to make it a [mcve]. The more specific you can be with where you are now, the better we can help you

Comment: Sure, ill be sure to edit it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this datafame:

```
        Date     Record_Type                                    Location Proterty_Type   Price
0  19-Mar-21  Active Listing              Sky Tower Downtown Los Angeles     Apartment   15000
1  19-Mar-21  Active Listing  Central Park Residential Tower, 5th Avenue     Apartment   17000
2  20-Mar-21  Active Listing                   Meadow Gardens, Park View         Villa  125000
```

Then:

```
keywords = ["Downtown", "Park View", "Industrial District"]

df.insert(
    loc=3,
    column="Area",
    value=df["Location"].apply(
        lambda x: next((kw for kw in keywords if kw in x), "Other")
    ),
)
print(df)
```

Creates `Area` column next to `Location` and prints:

```
        Date     Record_Type                                    Location       Area Proterty_Type   Price
0  19-Mar-21  Active Listing              Sky Tower Downtown Los Angeles   Downtown     Apartment   15000
1  19-Mar-21  Active Listing  Central Park Residential Tower, 5th Avenue      Other     Apartment   17000
2  20-Mar-21  Active Listing                   Meadow Gardens, Park View  Park View         Villa  125000
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you for that!, any place where you would recommend i check the documenntation for `lambda`?

Comment: @MahmoudAlQadi `lambda` is standard Python syntax, you can start at official Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions

Comment: trying this on a separate dateset, i got an error `TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable` what could be causing this? How would I make it skip floats?

Comment: @MahmoudAlQadi Shouldn't happen, is your column of type `string`? you can do before `df['Location'] = df['Location'].astype(str)`

Comment: they are strings but as there are so many values I haven't manually checked it all. your fix works tho, thank you!